# What is the ori instruction's importance in this code?

Tags: assembly, mips

```
# Add the first five integers 

.text 0x3000
.globl main
main:
 add   $8,$0,$0     # sum = 0
 add   $9,$0,$0     # for (i = 0; ...
loop:
 add   $8,$8,$9     # sum = sum + i;
 addi  $9,$9,1      # for (...; ...; i++
 slti  $10,$9,5     # for (...; i<5;
 bne   $10,$0,loop
end: 
 ori   $v0, $0, 10     # system call 10 for exit
 syscall               # we are out of here.
```

I am not quite sure what the `ori` instruction is doing in the end.
Once the loop has ended it has ended, so why is it significant?

Comment: the pseudo instruction `move` in MIPS is implemented by `addi` or `ori`. Isn't that stated in every MIPS syllabus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `ori` simply functions as `mov`.
This is because `ori  rd, rs, imm` is defined as `rd = rs | imm`.
When `rs` is the zero register, this simply means `rd = imm`.

If the CPU's instruction set doesn't have an actual `mov` instruction, a helpful assembler would translate the pseudo-instruction `mov rd, imm` to `ori rd, $0, imm`.

---

As for the loop and the ending, the thing is that an assembly language has no notion of "reaching the end of the program and exiting". Suppose your last coded instruction is located at address 0xDEADBEEF. After the CPU executes the instruction, it simply moves on to the next instruction address at 0xDEADBEF0. The next instruction address merely keeps incrementing until something happens, like a trap or whatnot.

So the conventional way to terminate a program is to make a system call. This transfers execution to the OS, kills the process, and never gives execution back to the process. To make a system call, you would put in appropriate values into registers - in this case, the value 10 is a command that the system will interpret as "exit process".

Comment: "the value 10 is a command that the system will interpret as "exit process". May you elaborate more on that ? I don't quite understand. Does putting ten in $v0 mean exit?

Comment: When the execution of your process reaches the line `syscall`, all the register values (including $v0) will be saved, and the OS starts executing. When the OS sees that $v0 = 10, it interprets that as the "exit process" command, destroys your process, and your process never continues execution (i.e. it exits).

Comment: Correct. Without the `syscall`, your program would continue executing below the last line, interpreting some garbage/random/zero memory values or causing a page fault. The program could potentially do any behavior, although it is *likely* to just crash quickly.

Comment: Remember, the binary code of your program is put into a memory space. Even after your part of the code ends, there are still more memory addresses after it. The CPU will continue blindly executing whatever is located in memory after your code.

Comment: I meant without putting 10 in the v0 register, would it still cause problems?

Comment: That would depend on what value was already in the register beforehand.